# theme not shows in Magento\app\design\frontend in magento 2?

Tags: magento

I have installed Magento 2 without composer

> Magento\app\design\frontend

and

> Magento\app\design\adminhtml folder shows empty.

How to show theme in

> Magento\app\design\frontend folder

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

What Magento version are you using?

In the public version of Magento 2, the theme folders were moved to:

> vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank
>
> vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma

and

> vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

D:\xampp1\htdocs\shopping\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma is showing but header.phtml and other cms pages not able to find ? Help me

Comment: The header.phtml is in "vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html"
The cms pages is in "vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/templates"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked after I ran the following command from the Magento 2 root folder:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

If it doesn't work, then you may run the command with `sudo`:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```